# How to maintain scroll position of FirebaseRecyclerAdapter

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

I am trying to maintain the scroll position of my `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` when I am returning to the same activity from another activity.

Here is my function which sets the `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`

```
public void setTheScreen(){
   FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Post,PostViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Post,PostViewHolder>(
           Post.class,
           R.layout.post_display_blueprint,
           PostViewHolder.class,
           postsNode
   ) {
       @Override
       public void onDataChanged() {
           if(dialog != null && dialog.isShowing()){
               dialog.dismiss();
           }
       }

       @Override
       protected void populateViewHolder(final PostViewHolder viewHolder, Post model, int position) {
           final String key = getRef(position).getKey();
           mRefPosts = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("posts").child(key);
           mLoveNode = mRef.child("loves");
           mRefLoves = mRef.child("loves").child(key);
           viewHolder.setTitle(model.getTitle());
           viewHolder.setLoves(mRefLoves);
           viewHolder.setLoveButton(Uid,key);
           viewHolder.setImage(getApplicationContext(),model.getImageUrl());


           mRefPosts.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
               @Override
               public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                   String isAnonymous = dataSnapshot.child("anonymous").getValue(String.class);
                   if (isAnonymous != null && isAnonymous.equals("true")) {
                       viewHolder.anonymousButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                   }

               }
               @Override
               public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

               }
           });


            viewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,PostDisplayPageActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("Key",key);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            });
       }
   };
   mRecyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
    firebaseRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

}

By clicking on any view created by the adapter I am going to a new activity named *PostDisplayPageActivity* from my *MainActivity* and on back pressing I am finishing the *PostDisplayPageActivity* and coming back to *MainActivity*.

When I come back to my MainActivity the list starts from the 0 position

I used the following code in my onPause and onResume methods, but it is not working.

```
 @Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    currentVisiblePosition = ((LinearLayoutManager)mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,String.valueOf(currentVisiblePosition),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    setTheScreen();
    mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(currentVisiblePosition);
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,String.valueOf(currentVisiblePosition),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    currentVisiblePosition = 0;


}
```

From those 2 `Toasts` I am getting the correct positions but the view always starts from position 0.

for my `RecyclerView` I am using `LinearLayoutManager` as *mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayoutManager);*

Someone please tell me what am I doing wrong or suggest me a different way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

I solved my problem with a simpler solution. I just called adapter.startListening(); in onViewCreated() instead of onStart and called adapter.stopListening(); in onDestroyView() instead of onStop()
That prevented the entire list from regenerating while coming back from next activity and thus retained the scroll position where it was previously.

Answer (score 0):

Having faced the same problem, I found numerous suggestions that did not work for me. So, I came up with a workaround for this issue of restoring the `Firebase RecyclerView` state/scroll position.

Keep a field of the instance state of the RecyclerView `instanceStateFirebaseRecycler` in the Activity/Fragment where the `Firebase RecyclerView` is implemented:

```
private Parcelable instanceStateFirebaseRecycler;
```

First, save the Firebase RecyclerView's instance state `instanceStateFirebaseRecycler`, which keeps the scroll position information, `onPause()`:

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    saveScrollPosition();
    super.onPause();
}
```

where the `saveScrollPosition()` method is simply:

```
private void saveScrollPosition(){
    instanceStateFirebaseRecycler = firebaseRecyclerView.getLayoutManager().onSaveInstanceState();
}
```

Next is the tricky part, you add a listener to your `Firebase Adapter` that notifies you when the adapter is ready, that is, when the `getItemCount()` is not zero. In the listener's callback you restore the recycler's state/scroll position:

```
firebaseAdapter = new FirebaseAdapter(options, new FirebaseAdapter.OnRestoreRecyclerStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRestoreRecyclerState() {
            restoreScrollPosition();
        }
    });
    firebaseRecyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseAdapter);
```

where the custom `interface` is just:

```
public interface OnRestoreRecyclerStateListener {
    void onRestoreRecyclerState();
}
```

and the `callback` is triggered in the `Firebase Adapter` `onBindViewHolder` (I did't find the better place) to make sure the adapter items are ready:

```
@Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull MyModel model) {
    ...
    onRestoreRecyclerStateListener.onRestoreRecyclerState();
}
```

, and where the `restoreScrollPosition()` method is:

```
private void restoreScrollPosition(){
    if (instanceStateFirebaseRecycler == null) return;
    firebaseRecyclerView.getRootView().setVisibility(View.GONE);
    final Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (instanceStateFirebaseRecycler == null) return;
            firebaseRecyclerView.getLayoutManager().onRestoreInstanceState(instanceStateFirebaseRecycler);
            instanceStateFirebaseRecycler = null;
            firebaseRecyclerView.getRootView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }, 100);
}
```

In the `restoreScrollPosition()` method I check for `instanceStateFirebaseRecycler == null` to avoid unnecessary runs. Also, I delay the instance state restoration by means of `Handler`, because the `items` are not drawn yet and will be shortly. If `onRestoreInstanceState` is called without delay, the state will not be restored as expected. Additionally, I toggle the `RecyclerView`'s visibility by `setVisibility()` to hide ugly items reloading and fast scrolling that can be interpreted by the user as glitches.

By the way, the solution suggested by @Sanju looks a bit dangerous in terms of traffic and battery efficiency, since a user can put a running app in the background for a long time with the listener being active for all this time.